# glm glx rotation does not work

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, glm-math

I'm working on a drive simulation project.I'm using opengl on VS2010 IDE.

There is a vector glm::vec3 'dir' for object 'car_param'(not important) which I want to rotate using glm\glx rotate function.

```
glm::rotate(car_param->dir,0.5f,glm::vec3(0,1,0));
```

It is being successfully compiled but when running it has no effect.
I tried to test it with:

```
cout<<car_param->dir.x<<"\t"<<car_param->dir.y<<"\t"<<car_param->dir.z<<"\n";
```

just after the rotate but it is stucked on (0,0,-1) which was the initial value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Look](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/api/a00200.html#gab556da0efabc9606f198f89a74cb1964) at the signature of `rotate()`:

```
template< typename T >
detail::tvec3< T > rotate( detail::tvec3< T > const &v, T const &angle, detail::tvec3< T > const &normal )
```

Note that `v` is passed in as a *const* reference.

`rotate()` *returns* a rotated vector.  It doesn't (can't!) rotate `v` in-place.

Try this:

```
car_param->dir = glm::rotate(car_param->dir,0.5f,glm::vec3(0,1,0));
```